# Spring JPA Lock Table and propagate the transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a class method that extracts some row from the database and sets a lock.

```
public interface PersonRep extends JpaRepository<Person, String> {

    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    @Query(value = "SELECT p FROM Person as p WHERE p.fProcessed = false")
    List<Person>  fetchPersonToProccess(@Param("name") String name,Pageable pageable);
}
```

I have a Service Layer that calls the above method as

```
@Service
public class PersonService{

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Person> fetchPersonToProccess(String name, Pageable pageable) {
        return personRep.fetchPersonToProccess(name, pageable);      
    }
}
```

I need to process those result rows into another method of a class without leaving the lock.

```
@Service
public class PersonProcess{
    @Transactional
    public List<Person> fetchPersonToProccess(UpdateRequest updateRequest, int numPage){
        //Process Row
        personService.fetchPersonToProccess(..);
    }
}
```

I would like the lock to be released at the end of the second method into class PersonProcess. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you sure? It should work just like that

Comment: Why you are using `@Transactional` in service ?

Comment: @AbinashGhosh where would he? In webservice??:>

Comment: I Have a class repository @repository that extend jparepository and a class service that implements the method insert, delete e select using the jpa. I have the necessary call the select with a lock. Lock working into a transaction. What are the errors?